# What's this kind of authentication scheme called?

Tags: hash, identity, identification

In the past I've heard about a scheme to prove your identity online in places like forums, without having to create an account.

When posting, the user would enter a password which is then heavily hashed and displayed publicly along with the post. This way the user can prove his identity between posts without having to create an account with a fixed name and password.

I'm not sure what to Google for. So far I've found the term ["commitment scheme" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aUser_committed_identity), but googling further on that, I can't find other places using it (though I'm sure there have to be some).

Does this kind of commitment scheme (publicizing a password hash) have a name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Displaying a hash of nick and password to identify users is known as *Tripcode*.

There are different variants of this, sometimes the website operator adds a secret key, sometimes an expensive hash like PBKDF2 or bcrypt is used, sometimes the password is replaced by public key.

Comment: Etymology please...